# How to play video in reverse in html

Tags: html, html5-video

I need to play video in reverse (last to first). How to do this requirement.

```
I tried this 

myVideo.playbackRate = -1;

But not working
```

Comment: It will work in Dafari with MP4 videos

Comment: in crome video is displaying and fast playback is working, but in safari video is not display

Comment: I tried it in Safari,it is working

Comment: Playing it backwards would require decoding the whole stream, storing each raw frame on the disk to avoid clobbering memory, then rendering the frames backwards.

Comment: One guy has did it in mplayer   check out this link   http://madcompscientist.blogspot.in/2009/03/sdrawkcab-oediv-gniyalp.html

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers support playbackRate yet. 
Only WebKit-based browsers support it, right now as Safari, Chrome, PSX3.

Good Luck!